# Accessing the attributes/elements of a form in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Hello so I've a form and I'm trying to make it so that when that form is validated. But before it is saved. It will create a new instance of a EC_Node and save the command given in the Command_Form not only to the Command_Node but to the EC_Nodes. Which should have a manytoone relationship with the Command_Nodes and which should record all commands send to a command_node. But this will only work if when entering a command for the Command_Node I also capture that in a EC_Node. Which I don't know how to do exactly although I'm some ideas.

So any advice would be greatly appreciated. Relevant Code follows.

**Relevant views.py**

```
def update(request, host_id):
    host_id = Command_Node.objects.get(pk=host_id)
    form = Command_Form(request.POST or None, instance=host_id)
    if form.is_valid():
        
        # Original suggestion was command_form = Command_Form.objects.first()
        command_form = form['host_id']
        command_form.EC_Node_set.all()  # <- not sure with all _ and Maj here
        
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
    return render (request, 'update.html', {'host_id':host_id,'form':form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class Command_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Command_Node
        fields = ('host_id','current_commands')

        host_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            required=True,
            queryset=Beacon.objects.all(),
            widget=forms.SelectMultiple(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                },
            )
        )

        current_comamnds = forms.ChoiceField(
            required=True,
            choices=CHOICES
        )

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        EC_Node.objects.create(
        command=self.cleaned_data["current_commands"],
        Command_node=self.instance
        )
        return super().save(**kwargs)
```

**models.py**

```
class Command_Node(models.Model):
    host_id = models.ForeignKey(Beacon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_commands = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=50, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.host_id)

class EC_Node(models.Model):
    Command_node = models.ForeignKey(Command_Node, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    command = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=50, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Command_node)
```

When I try to update things, via the update-view the present error I'm getting is:

```
'BoundField' object has no attribute 'EC_Node_set'
```

Thus my question on here. Thanks.

Comment: The error you have refers to a line. Please tell us which line have triggered your error message.

Comment: Hi pretty sure its "command_form.EC_Node_set.all()  # <- not sure with all _ and Maj here "

Answer (score 1):

Forms validated data are accessible in the `Form.cleaned_data` attribute. [See the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data).

So you need to access your user data using this dictionary:

```py
def update(request, host_id):
    host_id = Command_Node.objects.get(pk=host_id)
    form = Command_Form(request.POST or None, instance=host_id)
    if form.is_valid():
        
        # Original suggestion was command_form = Command_Form.objects.first()
        command_form = form.cleaned_data['host_id']
```